# Show that a collection of Borel-subsets are Borel.

Tags: measure-theory

Let T be a rotation of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ about the origin. I want to show that the collection of subsets $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $T(A)$ is Borel is a $\sigma$-algebra. I.e. show that $\mathfrak{A} = \{A \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: T(A) \textrm{ is Borel} \}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

$T(\emptyset) = \emptyset \in \mathfrak{A}$ and $T(\mathbb{R}^{2})$ is also Borel, since $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is open and T is continuous $T(\mathbb{R}^{2})$ is also open and therefore Borel.

Can I claim that for any set $B \in \mathfrak{A} $, $B^C$ is also Borel and therefore $B^{C} \in \mathfrak{A}$ and that the the union of sequences $B_{1}, B_{2},.. \in \mathfrak{A}$ are also Borel and the union is threfore in the set $\mathfrak{A}$.

I am unsure whether you can simply state that for example that $B^{C}$ lies in $\mathfrak{A}$ if $B \in \mathfrak{A}$ since $B$ is Borel.

Comment: It is helpful to note that $T$ has a continuous inverse.

Comment: The operations of complementation and union commute with any permutation

Comment: Do you mean $T(B^{C}) = T(B)^{C}$

Comment: That's right.  I added an answer with further explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on a set $X$, and $T$ is a permutation of $X$ (that is, a bijection $X \to X$,) then $\{A \subset X : T[A] \in S\}$ is also a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$.  This is because $T[A^\complement] = T[A]^\complement$ and if $(A_i : i \in \mathbb{N})$ is any sequence of sets in $X$ we have $T[\bigcup_{i\in \mathbb{N}} A_i] = \bigcup_{i\in \mathbb{N}} T[A_i]$.

(I'm using $T[A]$ rather than $T(A)$ to denote the pointwise image of a set $A$ under the function $T$.)